# nhibernate: project a Parent from a child-query

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I have the following entities

```
public class ArticleCategory
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public IList<Article> Articles {get; set;}
}

public class Article
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public ArticleCategory Category {get; set;}
}

public class JobArticles
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public Job Job {get; set;}
  public decimal Price {get; set;}
  public Article Article {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see Article knows nothing about to which JobArticle it has been assigned (it's not relevant)

So what I need to do is the following.
Get every ArticleCategory for which there exist JobArticles for Job X.

The easiest way would be to Add the List of JobArticles to the Article Entity. But I'm not sure if it is the best way.

So I tried the opposite way (going from JobArticle to ArticleCategory). Something like that

```
IQueryOver<JobArticle, JobArticle> q = DataSession.Current.QueryOver<JobArticle>();

        Article ArticleAlias = null;
        ArticleCategory ArticleCategoryAlias = null;

        q.JoinAlias(x => x.Article, () => ArticleAlias);
        q.JoinAlias(x => ArticleAlias.Category, () => ArticleCategoryAlias);
        q.Where(x => x.Job.Id == jobId);
        q.SelectList(list => list
            .Select(x => ArticleCategoryAlias))
```

Which leads to a NULL-Reference Exception because `.Select(x => ArticleCategoryAlias)`

I'm not really sure how to do it, hope you can help

Comment: If you need more information, I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Article ArticleAlias = null;
ArticleCategory ArticleCategoryAlias = null;

var categories = DataSession.Current.QueryOver<ArticleCategory>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(QueryOver.Of<JobArticle>()
        .JoinAlias(x => x.Article, () => ArticleAlias);
        .JoinAlias(x => ArticleAlias.Category, () => ArticleCategoryAlias);
        .Where(x => x.Job.Id == jobId);
        .Select(() => ArticleCategoryAlias.Id))
    .List();
```

Comment: sorry, took a long time, I just implemented and tested your solution. Didn't need it before (and couldn't test it)

I'm not sure if it's a nhibernate version thing, but I had to change `.WithSubquery.Where` to `.WithSubquery.WhereProperty`

Comment: As far i recall i wrote it from the top of my head. fixed.